# How to know which is the latest opportunity from multiple opportunities

Tags: apex, soql, community, salesforce1-app

Hi friends i got a requirement to update a field on case.Based on latest opportunity from account.

So,i wrote a trigger but how to know which is the latest opportunity.

I am thinking to calculate subtraction of today date with creation date of an opportunity.But any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Have you thought about using `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1` in the query on the Trigger?

Comment: It should work, although I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the latest Opportunity in the Trigger would be to, whilst querying, ordering by the `CreatedDate`, sorting it and limiting it.

```
Opportunity latestOpportunity = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :myAccountVariable ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];
```

In a nutshell:

- Select records from Opportunity related to the Account
- Order by the date it was created, descending, so the most recent one is retrieved first
- Limit by 1 because you're not after any more than that

I'm not sure how efficient this would be in the long run, but it would do what you're after.

Comment: Works like charm.@Dan Jones